# How can I export this .ai file to SVG while maintaining full shape

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, export, 3d, autocad

I have the following hand drawn .ai file that I would like to convert to SVG for 3d printing with tinkercad.

[image]

when I save as SVG however there is some clipping done to the paths and it turns out like:

[image]

with that file exported as SVG then, the 3d print preview comes out as follows:[image]

How can I correctly export the original .ai file so that the 3d print would be one solid piece that is just a 3d version of the original stroke path?

Comment: use pathfinder tool and merge all paths :) i suppose it should work

Comment: thank you that was what I needed on the SVG file. Turned out great

Answer (score 4):

Artwork needs to be prepared for these machines (3d printers, vinyl cutters, lasers, etc). In your case select everything and do a 'Pathfinder → Unite', then go into outline mode <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> and cleanup any leftover bits. Make sure you are left with a single, clean object before doing the SVG export.

Comment: Great thank you, I was planning on trying this out on a laser cutter as well so I will take this approach.